# How can I set a BuildConfig Git source ref to be a GitHub pull request?

Tags: openshift

In the [OpenShift docs for Git Source input](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-code), it says the following:

> If the ref field denotes a pull request, the system will use a git fetch operation and then checkout FETCH_HEAD.

However, there's no example that I can find of what needs to put as the ref for it to match a pull request. I can't figure out what it should be, and each variation that I've tried, I get an error such as this:

> error: build error: error: pathspec 'pull/128/head' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Variations that I've tried:

- refs/pull/128/head
- pull/128/head
- pull/128
- 128
- PR-128
- origin/pr/128/head
- origin/pr/128/merge

Any help appreciated, thanks!

---

**Edit:** updating with new info based on Graham's suggestion in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301845/how-can-i-set-a-buildconfig-git-source-ref-to-be-a-github-pull-request#comment77570263_45301845):

> I am not sure if it shows anything extra or not for that part, but set `BUILD_LOGLEVEL=9` as environment variable for the build configuration.

Setting `BUILD_LOGLEVEL=9` shows the following:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/<org>/<repo>" ...
I0725 13:43:32.297019 1 source.go:134] git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/<org>/<repo>
...
git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/<org>/<repo>
...
git checkout <branch>
```

For this, all of the regular branches are displayed, but not the PR heads (this is reproducible with any repo...remove the `--heads` option and you'll see all tags and PR heads too).

```
source.go:236] Cloning source from https://github.com/<org>/<repo>
...
git clone https://github.com/<org>/<repo> /tmp/docker-build989528171
...
git checkout origin/pr/128/merge
...
repository.go:427] Error executing command: exit status 1
...
helpers.go:116] error: build error: error: pathspec 'origin/pr/128/head' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I'm not sure how to give it something that it would accept for the `checkout`. I don't see a way to get it to fetch those heads to some refspec locally (like how Jenkins does e.g. `git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<org>/<repo>.git +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`

---

**Edit 2:** Added more information on things that I've tried

I've also now tried adding a `.gitconfig` file to the secret that I've got set in the BuildConfig (this secret also has the basic auth credentials to be able to clone from GitHub over https). The only thing in the .gitconfig is a refspec to try to get it to fetch the PR head references:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

This didn't seem to help either, even if I try with a `ref` value of `origin/pr/128/head`, so it seems like that refspec doesn't get fetched.

As mhutter suggests in the comments, passing in the sha1 of the actual commit with `--commit` seems to get what I want, but in what I understand as an "ignore the value of the ref, and use this instead" workaround way.

Comment: I am not sure if it shows anything extra or not for that part, but set ``BUILD_LOGLEVEL=9`` as environment variable for the build configuration.

Comment: Have you tried `origin/pr/1674/merge`? I implemented my PR builder in OpenShift similarly, I use the target branch in the BuildConfig and then use `oc start-build <bcname> --commit <sha1commit>`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks for the suggestion! I've added more info to the post based on that.

Comment: @mhutter I've tried that pathspec (and added it to the list of variations in the question), but it didn't help. If you set the branch in the BC, why do you need to pass in `--commit <sha1commit>`? Surely the branch ref would be enough, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug around using pull refs until recently:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1447495

Unless you're using origin 3.6.0-rc.0, that that is likely what you're hitting.

The docs reflect the state of origin master.

"refs/pull/58/head" should be the right format (once you're on a version of OpenShift that has the fix).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, that looks to be exactly the behaviour that I'm seeing. For anyone else reading this, passing the commit with `--commit` or similar seems to be a decent workaround until you move to the new version with the fix.